# Is there a way to eliminate repetitive stages in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a declarative pipeline where I have multiple stages that are identical, aside from two to three parameters within a bat command.  Basically each stage runs the same application on the agent, with only the arguments passed to the application changing.  Right now I have 10+ stages that are identical, except for 2 or 3 words in the stage.

I'm trying to find a way to basically write the stage once, and then run it over and over with different parameters.  I was going to try to use a function, however, I've read that it's not possible to run pipeline commands from functions. Since my stages are using the Bat command, I don't think I can use a function.

Am I stuck with all the nearly identical stages, or is there a better way to handle it?

A simplified version of my stages would look something like this...

```
Stages
{
    Stage ('First Stage')
    {
        steps {
            script {
                def programToRun = "\"${env.APPLICATION_PATH}\" /path:Output /file:FirstFile"                   

                def errorLevel = bat(
                    returnStatus: true,
                    script: scripttoExecute
                )
                if (errorLevel == 0)
                {
                    DoSomething()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    Stage ('Nth Stage')
    {
        steps {
            script {
                def programToRun = "\"${env.APPLICATION_PATH}\" /path:Output /file:NthFile"                 

                def errorLevel = bat(
                    returnStatus: true,
                    script: scripttoExecute
                )
                if (errorLevel == 0)
                {
                    DoSomething()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function without an issue. Check the sample below.

```
myVar = 1

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Stage1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    myFunction("STAGE1")   
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Stage2') {
            steps {
                script {
                    myFunction("STAGE2")   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def myFunction(def input) {
    sh "echo $input"
    echo "$myVar"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The only problem I found is that I was updating pipeline variables within each stage, but I get an error if I try to do that in the function.  At the beginning of the file I have `def myVar = 1`, if I try to access myVar in the function I get a property not found error.

Comment: @Tim remove the `def` keyword from the variable declaration which will make it a global variable. Chek the updated Pipeline.